# How to use flowvariable in a Mule Query

Tags: mule, datamapper

I am trying to use a query with flowvariable in the where clause in Mule ESB (Connecting with Salesforce)

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE CX_ID__c = '"flowvars.orgpayload.CXM_ID+"' LIMIT 1
```

But I am not getting an error here. Any pointers on how to use flow variable in a query would help. Thanks!

Comment: Where does this query fit? Can you show the full XML element where you use it? It's hard to provide a complete answer without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow variables are accessible via MEL, either with `flowVars.VAR_NAME`, `flowVars['VAR_NAME']` (if the variable contains characters that conflicts with MEL's syntax) or directly `VAR_NAME` (if you have not disabled the default binding of flow variables as top level MEL variables).

In your case, since the flow variable is named `orgpayload.CXM_ID`, the `.` makes it conflict with MVEL syntax. So you can not use `flowVars.orgpayload.CXM_ID` but instead you must use `flowVars['orgpayload.CXM_ID']`

PS. MEL is case sensitive. You typed `flowvars` when you wanted `flowVars`

Comment: i had another question on the bigger picture of the flow. I have posted it as a new question. if you could help throw some light on it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would have something like the blow

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE CX_ID__c = '#[flowVars['orgpayload.CXM_ID']]' LIMIT 1
```

In addition to the above, you should consider using *Parameterized* queries instead of *dynamic queries* as dynamic queries are prone to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and are less performant when compared to *Parameterized* queries.

Refer to this [document](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Database+Connector)